# How To Correctly Combine Django-Allauth and Custom User Profile App?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I've created a new app called **users** with the model **Profile**. For authentication I'm using **django-allauth** with *Facebook* and *Google* providers. Once user is logged in, I'd like to create a profile with some additional information populated from social providers, like: *full_name, email, picture*.

Here is what I have in the **models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=500)
    picture = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(user_signed_up)
    def populate_profile(sociallogin, user, **kwargs):

        user.profile = Profile()

        if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook':
            user_data = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='facebook')[0].extra_data
            picture_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + sociallogin.account.uid + "/picture?type=large"
            email = user_data['email']
            full_name = user_data['name']

        if sociallogin.account.provider == 'google':
            user_data = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='google')[0].extra_data
            picture_url = user_data['picture']
            email = user_data['email']
            full_name = user_data['name']

        user.profile.picture = picture_url
        user.profile.email = email
        user.profile.full_name = full_name
        user.profile.save()
```

While logging with *Facebook*, I'm getting the following error message:

> [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

And when I try to log in with *Google*, I receive the following:

> DataError at /accounts/google/login/callback/
>   value too long for type character varying(100)

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to do a similar thing to you. Could you please share how you managed to create the user profile once the user signed up? I have an app called `social_login` which handles the registration/signup and another which is called `users` which is kind of similar to yours. How would I go about creating the userProfile once the user has signed up? e.g. How do I make use of the `user_signed_up` variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues are now solved. First error message I solved by adding:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = None
```

And for the second one I had to add **max_length=255** for the picture:

```
picture = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics', max_length=255)
```